# Unfinished Paper Undergraduate Admission

Tags: publications, mathematics, undergraduate, publishability

I am currently in high school and I have written a research paper about a topic in mathematics. The paper however is incomplete and there is still quite a lot of research left.

I am also writing my university admission essays right now and I have a strong desire that universities see whatever progress that I have made so far.

What do you think should I do? Do you think it is wise to send in unfinished unpublished paper or should I first publish whatever I have done so far and then publish the remaining paper later on?

Comment: Do you have an academic mentor helping you prepare this manuscript? Any amount of academic writing from a high schooler is impressive. A recommendation letter from your mentor detailing your contributions to the in-preparation manuscript would likely serve you best in the application process.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have a mentor. But it is certainly possible for me to summarise my contributions in my essays. Do you think it is a better idea to submit the summary rather than the actual manuscript?

Comment: What is the nature of this research? Unfortunately, I worry that promoting yourself with an unmentored manuscript may be more detrimental than helpful unless you're already established in the field with reputable co-authors on other papers. Otherwise, your research lacks the context it needs to be relevant/credible. I would reach out to a local mathematician (perhaps at a community college or university) and see if they can lend credence to your work with a letter of evaluation.